# Is there a way to remove the default package called application showing in PHPDocumentator?

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

PHPDoc shows a default application package, and cannot figure out how to remove it.

[image: Screen cap here]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you use PHPDoc on a new project, without any comments, it shows a package name Application as if I was using @package Application in a comment somewhere, which is not the case.